# Why i can not see the under the SlidingDrawer?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, slidingdrawer

I've been working on building a Calculator.
And now i want to work with SlidingDrawer from below.
but unfortunately it takes over on all the screen and
I can not see the buttons of the Calculator that need to be under the SlidingDrawer.

Can you help me please ?
This is my XML-code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="right|bottom"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH2"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_weight=".25"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:weightSum="1.0" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/seven"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:background="@drawable/custombuttonsimple"
    android:text="7"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/eight"
    android:text="8"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:background="@drawable/custombuttonsimple"
    />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/nine"
    android:text="9"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:background="@drawable/custombuttonsimple"
    />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/div"
    android:text="/"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:background="@drawable/custombulebutton"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH3"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_weight=".25"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:weightSum="1.0" >
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/four"
    android:text="4"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:background="@drawable/custombuttonsimple"
    />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/five"
    android:text="5"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:background="@drawable/custombuttonsimple"
    />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/six"
    android:text="6"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:background="@drawable/custombuttonsimple"
    />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/mul"
    android:text="*"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:background="@drawable/custombulebutton"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH4"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_weight=".25"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:weightSum="1.0" >
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:text="1"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:background="@drawable/custombuttonsimple"
    />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:text="2"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:background="@drawable/custombuttonsimple"
    />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/three"
    android:text="3"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:background="@drawable/custombuttonsimple"
    />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/pluse"
    android:text="+"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:background="@drawable/custombulebutton"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH5"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_weight=".25"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:weightSum="1.0" >
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/zero"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:background="@drawable/custombuttonsimple"
    />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/dot"
    android:text="."
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:background="@drawable/custombulebutton"
    />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/equal"
    android:text="="
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:background="@drawable/customgreenbutton"
    />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/minus"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:background="@drawable/custombulebutton"
    />
</LinearLayout>
    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle"
         >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Handle" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hellow,"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rate"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ratingBar1"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="Rate us:"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/Aquamarine" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rate"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>
      </SlidingDrawer>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay try taking a parent relative layout and then take another child which is again a relative layout and then in that child node which is a relative layout add that sliddindrawer there and set the padding and check